# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли тут запятая: "Придет время(,) и она сама изменится"? Никак не соображу, какое это предложение: сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Структуру предложения можно трактовать по-разному. Скорее всего правильнее его считать сложносочинённым союзным. Но в принципе можно трактовать и как сложноподчинённое предложение с опущенным союзным словом: "(Когда) придёт время, и она сама изменится", тогда "И" здесь не союз, а усилительная частица. То есть кто-то ещё уже изменился или изменится, а "она" - только когда время придёт. Но на постановку запятой это никак не влияет.